# Form validation of Sign Up Fields with amplify-ui 2.0 in addition to CheckboxField in the React

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am using amplify-ui 2.0 for my React application.
The docs ([document link](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/components/authenticator#sign-up-fields)) show an example of Sign Up Fields validation for CheckboxField using validateCustomSignUp, but how can I validate the other custom field? For example, I added name field, and added custom code for validateCustomSignUp, but it does not work.

The code is

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator
      // Default to Sign Up screen
      initialState="signUp"
      // Customize `Authenticator.SignUp.FormFields`
      components={{
        SignUp: {
          FormFields() {
            const { validationErrors } = useAuthenticator();

            return (
              <>
                {/* Re-use default `Authenticator.SignUp.FormFields` */}
                <Authenticator.SignUp.FormFields />
                
                <TextField
                        isRequired
                        key="name"
                        name="name"
                        label="name"
                        placeholder="name"
                 />

                {/* Append & require Terms & Conditions field to sign up  */}
                <CheckboxField
                  errorMessage={validationErrors.acknowledgement}
                  hasError={!!validationErrors.acknowledgement}
                  name="acknowledgement"
                  value="yes"
                  label="I agree with the Terms & Conditions"
                />
              </>
            );
          },
        },
      }}
      services={{
        async validateCustomSignUp(formData) {
          if (!formData.acknowledgement) {
            return {
              acknowledgement: 'You must agree to the Terms & Conditions',
            };
          }
           if (formData.name < 5) {
            return {
              name: 'Your name must be more than 5 characters ',
            };
          }
        },
      }}
    >
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It has been 4 months since you posted, so I hope you have figured it out by now. For anyone else with this issue, here is a solution.

```html
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator
      // Default to Sign Up screen
      initialState="signUp"
      // Customize `Authenticator.SignUp.FormFields`
      components={{
        SignUp: {
          FormFields() {
            const { validationErrors } = useAuthenticator();

            return (
              <>
                {/* Re-use default `Authenticator.SignUp.FormFields` */}
                <Authenticator.SignUp.FormFields />
                
                <TextField
                        isRequired="true"
                        errorMessage={validationErrors.name}
                        hasError={!!validationErrors.name}
                        key="name"
                        name="name"
                        label="name"
                        placeholder="name"
                 />

                {/* Append & require Terms & Conditions field to sign up  */}
                <CheckboxField
                  errorMessage={validationErrors.acknowledgement}
                  hasError={!!validationErrors.acknowledgement}
                  name="acknowledgement"
                  value="yes"
                  label="I agree with the Terms & Conditions"
                />
              </>
            );
          },
        },
      }}
      services={{
        async validateCustomSignUp(formData) {
          
          // Initialize conditions so they're a little more readable
          var acknowledgeValidation = !formData.acknowledgement;
          var nameValidation = formData.name.length < 5;
          
          // initialize error messages. We can't put them in separate if statements that return an
          // error
          var acknowledgeError = acknowledgeValidation ? "You must agree to the Terms!!!!!" : "";
          var nameError = nameValidation ? "You must put your full name!!!!!" : "";
          if (acknowledgeValidation || nameValidation) {
            return {
              name: nameError,
              acknowledgement: acknowledgeError,
            };
          }
        },
      }}
    >
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <main>
          <h1>Hello {user.username}</h1>
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
        </main>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  );
}
```

This works when I run it... although I didn't copy-paste it from my code so there could be a typo. It could be a little more compact if you want to avoid using those extra variables I made.